# uasort is leaving the custom-defined field unsorted

Tags: php, sorting, phpunit

So I have a function

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Classes;

class FieldSorter{

    public function sortFieldsByIndex($fields){

        $fields->uasort(function ($fa, $fb) {
            if ($fa->getIndex() == $fb->getIndex()) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($fa->getIndex() < $fb->getIndex()) ? -1 : 1;
        });
       return $fields
    }
}
```

which works and orders the fields when using an array object iterator. When I try to phpunit test it,

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Classes;

use MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Field;

class FieldSorterTest extends TestCase {

        protected $object;
        protected $field1;
        protected $field2;
        protected $fields = array();

    public function testSortFieldsByIndex(){

         $this->field1 = new Field();
         $this->field1->setIndex(4);


         $this->field2 = new Field();
         $this->field2->setIndex(3);

         $fields = new \ArrayObject(array($this->field1, $this->field2));
         $this->object = new FieldSorter();
         $fieldSorted = $this->object->sortFieldsByIndex($fields);
         // pre test
         echo $fieldSorted[0]->getIndex();
    }

}
```

The echo produces a 4, not 3....

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Try passing $fields by ref `&$fields`

Comment: @DannyYeshurun I get `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed` when trying that. @deceze forgot to add the return, now updated

Comment: Without a full executable example we can check ourselves this'll be difficult to debug…

Comment: @deceze is that enough now?

Comment: uasort maintains key association, see here http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php
print_r fieldSorted and you will figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $fieldSorted[0]->getIndex();
```

was the problem (thanks for the help in the comments). Instead, if I do

```
$count = 3;
foreach($fieldsSorted as $fieldSorted){
    $this->assertEquals($count, $fieldSorted->getIndex());
    $count++;
}
```

Then I get the tests passing, because the later index really does come later (e.g. 3 then 4)